# Unable to get current route inside component class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-router

I have a middleware set up checking for static needs, that essentially prepares async data before page is rendered, I ran into an issue while trying to pass my api call function `getWaitingListPosition` a token thats inside a route like so:

```
export default class WaitingListPage extends React.Component {
  static need = [
    getWaitingListPosition(this.props.routeParams.token)
  ]

  ...
}
```

I get an error saying `cannot read props of undefined`

This is using react-router v2.4.1

url that this component is accessed from: `https://mywebsite.com/w/:token`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static methods don't have access to instance (`this`) properties. You should make it such that it takes a prop of the routeParams and then calls the function.

```
static need = (routeParams) => {
  // make sure to return a promise
  return getWaitingListPosition(routeParams.token)
}
```

**Update**

This will need to be called during your render... something like this.

```
// assuming a promise, call the static method on the routed component
RoutedComponent.need(routeParams)
.then((data) => {
  render(<RoutedComponent data={data}/>)
}
```

Comment: I believe changing it to this approach doesn't execute the `getWaitingListPosition ` function, additionally `[ ]` should be swapped for `{ }`

Comment: Good point, my bad. Are you trying to make an onEnter type event?

Comment: In a way, I'm trying to fire this function before component renders, it gets stuff from api and continues the render

Comment: Is this a pattern you got from an example? I'm not sure that's the best way to go about it. You could always use `componentWillMount()`, are you wanting the data request to block rendering? or async?

Comment: This pattern is initially from this react starter that I am using: https://github.com/choonkending/react-webpack-node/blob/master/app/containers/Vote.jsx#L17 it waits before data is received before rendering

Comment: Ah ok, I understand exactly what you're trying to do. Let me update my answer.